# Chrome Extension won't load. Have I named the file incorrectly?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I built a simple chrome extension. It loaded correctly before, but now Chrome can't open it. I may have misnamed a file.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
       <title>Kalki </title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- LINK THROUGH TO THE CODEPEN SITE -->
<iframe src="https://codepen.io/Teeke/live/yLezNrE" width="1000" height="1000" frameborder="0" id="frame1" name="frame1"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I've validated the JSON in the manifest file and it passes:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "Kalki Chrome",
    "description": "Window to the world 2",

"icons":
{
"16": "images/kalki16.png", 
"48": "images/kalki48.png",
"128": "images/kalki128.png"
},


"browser_action":
{
"default_icon": "images/kalki48.png",
"default_popup": "kalki.html"
}


}
```

Comment: The code looks fine so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin wouldn't load because I had an extra folder level when I downloaded and zipped the project. I removed this extra folder, and put the three files at root level, and the plugin loaded correctly.